# Templates in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have few doubts with Index Templates  and using this templates when creating a new document.
1. PUT _template/template_1
I have mentioned only one field in mapping file which is custom analyzed.

```
 {
        "index_patterns": ["te*", "bar*"],
        "settings":{
             "analysis": {
                        "analyzer": {
                            "analyzer2": {
                                "filter": [
                                    "standard"
                                ],
                                "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                            },
                             "analyzer1": {
                                "filter": [
                                    "standard"
                                ],
                                "tokenizer": "tokenizer1"
                            }
                        },
                           "tokenizer": {
                            "tokenizer1": {
                                "min_gram": "3",
                                "tokenize_on_chars": [
                                    "letter",
                                    "digit"
                                ],
                                "type": "edge_ngram",
                                "max_gram": "3"
                            }
                        }
             }
        },
        "mappings": {
                "_doc": {
                    "properties": {
                        "search": {
                            "type": "text",

                            "fields": {
                               "analyzer1": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer":"analyzer1"
                                },
                               "analyzer2": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer":"analyzer2"
                                },

                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
     }
    }
 _template/template_1
```

2. POST /tea/_doc/1
 a new document of this type is created with a new metadata

```
{
    "search":"elastic",
    "metadata":"search"
}
```

3.GET /tea/_doc/_mapping
When is retrieve the mapping file, the newly added field is default analysed rather than custom analysed. How do I apply these custom analysers by default when a new metadata is found in the document

```
{
    "tea": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "search": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "analyzer1": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "analyzer1"
                            },
                            "analyzer2": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "analyzer2"
                            },
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [analyzer documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html#analyzer), if you name your analyzer "`default`" it will be used as the default analyzer.

From the documentation:

> At index time, Elasticsearch will look for an analyzer in this order:
>
> - The `analyzer` defined in the field mapping.
> - An analyzer named `default` in the index settings.
> - The `standard` analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer.  I have to mention two or three custom analyzers as default that has to be applied to a metadata when it is stored. Can you please provide an example as to how to apply a custom analyzer as default in index settings

Comment: make sure to accept the answer if you think it is the solution to the problem